# how to operate in airflow so that the task rerun and continue downstream tasks

Tags: scheduled-tasks, airflow

I set up a work flow in airflow, one of jobs was failed, after I fixed the problem, I want to rerun the failed task and continue the workflow.the details like below:

[image]

as above, I prepared to run the task "20_validation", I pressed the button 'Run' like below:

[image]

but the problem is when the task '20_validation' has finished, these downstream tasks were not continue to be started. How should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `clear` button directly below the `run` button you drew the box around in your screenshot.

This will clear the failed task state and all the tasks after (since downstream is selected to the right), causing them all to be run/rerun.

Since the upstream task failed, the downstream tasks shouldn't have been run anyway, so it shouldn't cause successful tasks to rerun.

Comment: ok,I will try, how to mark a task instance success status and skip it if it is running?I am newer on airflow, thank you so much

Comment: If the scheduler is already running the task, then there isn't anything you can do to stop that process short of killing it on the system level.  You can mark the downstream task states to success (or failed) to prevent them from running, or mark the entire dag run state to success or failed to stop it from running further.  But once the schedule kicks off the task it wait to see if the task was successful or not and then update the task instance accordingly.